# VBA (Microsoft Excel) replace Array with String

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is completely wrong, but at the moment, I really don't know how to do it.

In Microsoft Excel, I want to replace all the values on the "OldValues" string, by a fixed string "NewValue". How is that possible?

LBound and Ubound are wrong to be used, right?

```
Sub Replace()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim OldValues As Variant
Dim NewValue As String
Dim x As Long

OldValue = Array("old1","old2","old3")
NewValue = "allnew!"

  For x = LBound(OldValue) To UBound(NewValue)

      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=OldValue(x), Replacement:=NewValue(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be working with minor changes:
`NewValue` is not an array, so `UBound(NewValue)` will get you an error. You have to go up to `UBound(OldValues)` instead in your loop, and remove the `(x)` after `NewValue` in the `Replace`.

```
Sub Replace()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim OldValues As Variant
Dim NewValue As String
Dim x As Long

OldValues = Array("old1","old2","old3")
NewValue = "allnew!"

  For x = LBound(OldValues) To UBound(OldValues)

      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=OldValues(x), Replacement:=NewValue, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one. Don't know properly the function LBound & Ubound (as i understood, they exist to create a loop searching on an array?), so I didn't know how to put it working.

Comment: When used with an array they refer to the upper and lower index boundaries, so with the array of `Array("old1","old2","old3")` - `LBound` will be 0 and `UBound` will be 2

Comment: @MiguelRasquinho Alternately you can iterate over an array using a variable of type variant and a For Each Loop.  `Dim x as Variant:  For Each x in OldValues`

Comment: Thank you both! It worked as expected, and now I can properly understood the `LBound` and `UBound` .